# issue with hierarchical queries in db2

Tags: sql, db2, hierarchical-query

I have the following tables

Lead

- id varchar
- employee_id varchar

Employee

- id varchar
- lead_id varchar

There will be a group of employees assigned to a lead. The Lead table holds the employee id of the lead.
The employee table will have lead_id which will be the id key of the leader.

The table will also contain employees which are not assigned to any lead

I need a query which will display the hierarchical result which will list the leaders and the employees under the leader

leader1 (employee )

- employee1
- employee 2

Leader 2(employee)

- employee 3
- employee 4

Any idea how this kind of hierarchical result can be obtained  by a db2 query?

[Click on the this link to view the table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nChai.png)

Comment: Hierarchical queries are pretty simple in DB2. Do you want just two levels (as in your example), or all levels? If you add some sample data I can write the response in no time.

Comment: yes, I just need 2 levels , I am editing the question to add sample data you requested

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a join of the two tables like

```
SELECT l.employee_id as leader_employee_id, e.id as employee_id  
  FROM LEAD l
 INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e
    ON e.lead_id = l.employee_id
```